# how to get current date from server in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, server

I am sending today date to server but server shows yesterday date what's wrong with me?
here i am using the code for getting date and sending date .

```
NSString *dateValue = borntext.text;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateValue];
long dateInMillis = [date timeIntervalSince1970];



NSString *actDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date(%@)/",born];

        NSString *nDate = [[[[actDate componentsSeparatedByString:@"("] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@")"] objectAtIndex:0];

        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([nDate doubleValue])];

        NSDateFormatter *dtfrm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dtfrm setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy "];

        nDate = [dtfrm stringFromDate:date];
```

her i am converting milliseconds to date from server and sending date is convert to milli seconds.so please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: can u show your server response

Comment: -29548800 this date in milli econds

Comment: online utc converter shows correct time and server not showing correct date it is swing oneway left\

Comment: hi if I try to convert this -29548800, but I am get the output like 31-12-1969, this is correct or u need something else

Comment: the actual time in 01/23/1969

Comment: can u try and share your code please?

Comment: Seems to me that this depends on the server.  A server is under no obligation to tell you what time is is at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to agree to use the same timezone, and GMT/UTC is generally accepted as the best common timezone.

Therefore set the `NSDateFormatter` timezone with:

```
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
```

The server "API" should document this; else I would raise it as a bug with the providers.

Comment: i accepted your answer but i am trying both time zones ,there is no use.

Comment: @guruprasadgudluri OK well it sounds like you need to contact the server admins, because as I mentioned, this should be documented by them.